# Android: How to block sms app launch in android

Tags: android, sms

I need to block SMS/ Messaging app from launch.. I need to know the appropriate recevier when the default messaging app of android is launched or is there any other way to do this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No.  And there shouldn't be-  it would be way too easy for malicious software to abuse by not letting people run their competitor's software, or to stop the user from being able to use their phone (in the case of a virus).

Comment: Actually there is an app named "App lock" which protects the messaging app by password.. i.e., wen we launch the app a authentication screen araises and after authentication the messaging app is launched.. Here they are doing some stuff to get that app is launched